# Prox of l-1 norm over l-2 unit ball

Tags: optimization, convex-analysis, convex-optimization, proximal-operators

I'm trying to figure out if there's a way to efficiently compute the proximal operator of $l1$ norm, constrained by the $l2$ unit ball.

Let $$f(\mathbf{x}) = \begin{cases}
&\|\mathbf{x}\|_1, &\|\mathbf{x}\|_2\leq 1\\
& \inf, &\text{else}
\end{cases}$$
Then the problem formulation is $$\text{prox}_f(\mathbf{x})=\text{argmin}_{\|\mathbf{u}\|_2\leq 1}\;\|\mathbf{u}\|_1+\frac{1}{2}\|\mathbf{u}-\mathbf{x}\|_2^2=\text{argmin}_{\|\mathbf{u}\|_2\leq 1}\;\|\mathbf{u}\|_1+\frac{1}{2}\|\mathbf{u}\|_2^2-\mathbf{x}^T\mathbf{u}$$

We notice that the two separable $\mathbf{u}$ terms are minimized at $\mathbf{0}$ while $-\mathbf{x}^T\mathbf{u}$ would be minimized when $\mathbf{u}=\frac{\mathbf{x}}{\|\mathbf{x}\|_2}$. I'm trying to figure out how we can balance between the two, clearly depending on the norm value of $\mathbf{x}$. Maybe based on some sort of root search, similar to the prox of projecting onto $l1$ ball?

Comment: Perhaps you could use the fact that $\|u\|_1 = \max_{\|\lambda\|_\infty \le 1} \lambda^T u$ and take the dual?

Comment: @copper.hat that's actually a very good idea. Doing so allows to use mini-max Theorem. What I have so far is: $\min_{\|\mathbf{u}\|_2 \leq 1}\max_{\|\mathbf{y}\|_{\infty}\leq 1} \mathbf{y}^T\mathbf{u} + 0.5\|\mathbf{u}\|_2^2-\mathbf{x}^T\mathbf{u}$. Then using mini-max, and since the function is convex in $\mathbf{u}$ and concave in $\mathbf{y}$:  $\max_{\|\mathbf{y}\|_{\infty}\leq 1} \min_{\|\mathbf{u}\|_2 \leq 1}\mathbf{y}^T\mathbf{u} + 0.5\|\mathbf{u}\|_2^2-\mathbf{x}^T\mathbf{u}$. Now the problem is the inner minimization depends on the norm $\|\mathbf{x-y}\|$. Ideas where to go from here?

Comment: @copper.hat also, since I'm interested in the **argmin** and not the actual minimum value, does mini-max even work here? Or there's a way to later attain it via Moreau decomposition?

Comment: I guess you can cascade the prox operators of individual functions. Say $f_1(x) = \| x \|_1$ and $f_2(x) = \delta_C(x)$, where $ \delta_C(x)$ is an indicator function to the set $C = \{ x : \|x\|_2 \leq 1 \}$. Then, $\operatorname{prox}_f = \operatorname{prox}_{f_1} \circ \operatorname{prox}_{f_2}$ ?

Comment: @user550103 unfortunately not. Composition works only if $f_1+f_2 < \infty$, which is not the case when $f_2 = \delta_c$.

Comment: @iarbel84 May be I am misunderstanding Proposition 12 of this paper https://carma.newcastle.edu.au/resources/jon/Preprints/Papers/Published-InPress/Douglas%20Ratchford/PAPERS/Bauschke%20et%20al/Combettes%20Douglas-Rachford07.pdf

Comment: @user550103 damn, you might be right. I saw the $\infty$ condition a while back in another article, but the one you referred says composition should be possible

Comment: @iarbel84 But I suspect sometimes that solution would be "accurate". One might have to resort to alternating projections like method to obtain a good solution. You can try and see if it works for you. I would be happy to hear the result :)

Comment: @user550103 reading through it again, I don't think composition works. Proposition 12 in the article states that it works only if $\mathbf{x}\in C$ **OR** if $C\subseteq\mathbb{R}$. I'm working over $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Comment: @iarbel84 I also recently found this article on the decomposition of proximal operators (I have not been able to digest this yet, but may be someday): https://www.math.univ-toulouse.fr/~fcaubet/Publications/2017%20-%20On%20the%20proximity%20operator%20of%20the%20sum%20of%20two%20closed%20and%20convex%20functions%20-%20Adly,Bourdin,Caubet.pdf

Answer (score 2):

What I think that could work, based on the idea to use duality / conjugate, is the following: calculate $f^*(\mathbf{y})$, then $\text{prox}_{f^*}$, and use Moreau decomposition $\text{prox}_{f}(\mathbf{x}) + \text{prox}_{f^*}(\mathbf{x}) = \mathbf{x}$ to get the desired result.

So far I could calculate $f^*(\mathbf{y})$, but still no luck with $\text{prox}_{f^*}$.

$$f^*(\mathbf{y}) = \max_{\|\mathbf{x}\|_2 \leq 1} \mathbf{x}^T\mathbf{y}-\|\mathbf{x}\|_1=\max_{\|\mathbf{x}\|_2 \leq 1} \mathbf{x}^T\mathbf{y}-\max_{\|\mathbf{u}\|_{\infty} \leq 1}\mathbf{x}^T\mathbf{u}=\max_{\|\mathbf{x}\|_2 \leq 1} \min_{\|\mathbf{u}\|_{\infty} \leq 1}\mathbf{x}^T\mathbf{y}-\mathbf{x}^T\mathbf{u},$$
and since the expression above is convex in $\mathbf{u}$, concave in $\mathbf{x}$, we can change the order of optimization to get
$$f^*(\mathbf{y})= \min_{\|\mathbf{u}\|_{\infty} \leq 1}\max_{\|\mathbf{x}\|_2 \leq 1}\mathbf{x}^T\mathbf{y}-\mathbf{x}^T\mathbf{u}\overset{\mathbf{x}=\frac{\mathbf{y-u}}{\|\mathbf{y-u}\|_2}}=\min_{\|\mathbf{u}\|_{\infty} \leq 1}\|\mathbf{y-u}\|_2=\|[\mathbf{|y|-1}]_+\|_2.$$

With $[\mathbf{|y|-1}]_+=\max\{|y_i|-1,0\}$ for every component $i=1,\dots,n$. However I got stuck from here on, and was not able to calculate $\text{prox}_{f^*}(\mathbf{y})=\text{argmin}_{\mathbf{u}\in\mathbb{R}^n} \|[\mathbf{|u|-1}]_+\|_2 + \frac{1}{2}\|\mathbf{u-y}\|_2^2$.

Ideas anyone? I assume the solution will require some 1-D root search, similar to the one used in the projection onto $l1$ ball. But any linear complexity algorithm is fine.

Comment: It doesn't help, but if $y \in \overline{B}_\infty$ then $\text{prox}_{f^*} (y) = y$.

Comment: Perhaps you could compute $\partial f^*(w)$? We have $f^*(y) = \|y-\text{proj}_{\overline{B}_\infty} y\|_2$.

Comment: Sorry, I am full of useless info :-). I thought I had a cute solution using Moreau, but it ended up in the same place as above.

Comment: Have you solved it since?